# ID problem when I change the status of a value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my form `revision`, I have 2 motorbikes in revision. There are the number `000001` and `000003`.

[image]

In my form `motorbikes`, I see that the ID of the motorbike `000002` has been modified instead of ID number `000003`.

[image]

There is a problem about ID ?

In my Controller motorbike I have this:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::oldest()->paginate(5);

        $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">", Carbon::now())->pluck('id')->toArray();

        return view('admin.motorbikes.index', compact('motorbikes', 'bikeIdsDown'))
          ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   public function create()
    {       

        $revisions = Revision::all();
        $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<" , Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">", Carbon::now())->pluck('id')->toArray();

        return view('admin.motorbikes.create', compact('revisions', 'motorbikes'));
    }
```

In my index.blade I also have this:

```
@foreach($motorbikes as $motorbike)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$motorbike->matriculation }} </td>
    <td>{{$motorbike->number_motorbike}}</td>
    <td> @if(in_array($motorbike->id, $bikeIdsDown))
           UNAVAILABLE
         @else
           Available
         @endif
     </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `$bikeIdsDown` is collecting the `id` of the **Revision**, not the motorbikes.  The FK of the **Motorbike** on the **Revision** model is `fk_motorbike`.  So... try changing the `$bikeIdsDown` query to pull the FK, not the revision id:

```
 $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<=" , Carbon::now())
      ->where('date_revision_end', ">=", Carbon::now())
      ->pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray(); //<-- fk of motorbike, not revision
```

Also note, I added `<=` and `>=` to the date comparisons - not sure if you wanted to include same day on the revisions or not.